Getting nested JSON value using a for-loop
I make the use of a function in my Python script to get a certain value. The value I want is the so-called 'parentComponentId' using the condition 'name' equal to 'Vinje'.
Here is the function:
def get_parentcomponentid(data, name):
return next(
    element["parentComponentId"]
    for element in data
    for x in element["meta"]
    if x["name"] == name)

The response I want to traverse is as follows:
 [
  {
     'powerPlant': {
      'name': 'Nore 2',
      'componentId': 7304,
      'spotlessId': 11,
      'timeSeries': None,
      'units': [
        {
          'generatorName': 'Nore 2 G2',
          'xyTimeSeries': None,
          'componentId': 73042,
          'timeSeries': None
        },
        {
          'generatorName': 'Nore 2 G1',
          'xyTimeSeries': None,
          'componentId': 73041,
          'timeSeries': None
        }
      ]
    },
    'meta': {
      'parentComponentId': 10024,
      'technologyType': 'Hydro',
      'regionId': 10,
      'priceArea': 1
    }
  },
  {
     'powerPlant': {
      'name': 'Vinje',
      'componentId': 7814,
      'spotlessId': 19,
      'timeSeries': None,
      'units': [
        {
          'generatorName': 'Vinje G1',
          'xyTimeSeries': None,
          'componentId': 78141,
          'timeSeries': None
        },
        {
          'generatorName': 'Vinje G3',
          'xyTimeSeries': None,
          'componentId': 78143,
          'timeSeries': None
        },
        {
          'generatorName': 'Vinje G2',
          'xyTimeSeries': None,
          'componentId': 78142,
          'timeSeries': None
        }
      ]
    },
    'meta': {
      'parentComponentId': 10034,
      'technologyType': 'Hydro',
      'regionId': 10,
      'priceArea': 2
    }
  }
]

However, using this set-up I get the error:
    return next(
    element["parentComponentId"]
    for element in data
    for x in element["meta"]
    >       if x["name"] == name)
    E   TypeError: string indices must be integers

Is it the structure of the function that expects an integer?

Can you fix your indentation? I don't want to try and do it wrong.

name is under powerPlant, you need do
def get_parentcomponentid(data, name):
    return next(
        element["meta"]["parentComponentId"]
        for element in data
        if element["powerPlant"]["name"] == "Vinje"
    )

